# Symfony2 getData is returning empty fields

Tags: forms, symfony, post

I have setup a form with no class, but when I submit it the field data is null.

Controller :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('barcode', 'text')
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->get('barcode')->getData();
        var_dump( $data );
    }

    return compact('form');
}
```

View :

```
<form action="{{ path('incompass_sterilization_scanning_index') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="form-inline scan">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.barcode) }}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode" style="font-size:18px;"></span>
    <input type="text" id="barcode" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans %}Scan Bar Code{% endtrans %}" name="barcode" required="required" autofocus="true" />
</form>
```

When I enter antying into barcode, the result of the var_dump is always NULL

What have I done wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of the `name` html attribute of your form opening tag.
instead of `<form .... >` and `</form>`, use `{{ form_start(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}`
or add a `name="form"` to your form opening tag.
the name attribute must be the same as the name of your form in symfony.if you create your form with `$this->createFormBuilder()` it will be "form" but you can set whatever name you want using the form factory's `createNameBuilder`.when you render the opening tag of your form form with `{{ form_start(form) }}` symfony will automatically take care of it for you.Also keep in mind that creating named forms is especially useful (necessary) when you have multiple forms in one page ( to be more precise, when they're `action` is set to the same controller).